# openlayers3 bower install fail

Tags: bower, openlayers-3

I'm trying to install openlayers3 using bower and I have the following error:

```
>bower install ol3
bower ol3#~3.2.1            not-cached git://github.com/Yann29/bower-ol3.git#~3.2.1
bower ol3#~3.2.1               resolve git://github.com/Yann29/bower-ol3.git#~3.2.1
bower ol3#*                 not-cached git://github.com/Yann29/bower-ol3.git#*
bower ol3#*                    resolve git://github.com/Yann29/bower-ol3.git#*
bower ol3#*                   checkout master
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:   2% (23/808), 732.00 KiB | 80.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:   6% (49/808), 788.00 KiB | 80.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:   7% (57/808), 908.00 KiB | 83.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:   8% (66/808), 956.00 KiB | 83.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:  17% (138/808), 1.00 MiB | 86.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:  18% (146/808), 1.14 MiB | 87.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:  18% (147/808), 1.25 MiB | 87.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:  19% (157/808), 1.33 MiB | 91.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:  19% (161/808), 1.49 MiB | 99.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:  20% (163/808), 1.57 MiB | 103.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:  20% (163/808), 1.69 MiB | 103.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#*                   progress Receiving objects:  20% (163/808), 1.75 MiB | 105.00 KiB/s
bower ol3#~3.2.1          ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy ~3.2.1

Additional error details:
No versions found in git://github.com/Yann29/bower-ol3.git
```

I also tried bower install https://github.com/openlayers/ol3, but it still searches in https://github.com/openlayers/ol3.

Any ideeas on how could I install openlayers 3.2.1 ?

Comment: After some research I found out there's no repository yet with 3.2.1. I am using the build downloaded from openlayers oficial website.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this: `bower install ol3-bower#3.2.1` (versions up 3.13.1 are available). [Git repo](https://github.com/baasgeo/ol3-bower)